# Can a remote user (logged into my computer via LogMeIn) capture my password as I log into a website?

Tags: identity, remote-desktop, identity-theft, screen-capture

I work for a large company with IT support that uses LogMeIn to take control of our PCs when troubleshooting.  Today while being assisted I was asked to log into an internal website during a LogMeIn sessions in which the support analyst had control of my computer (presumably through RDP).  Is it possible for the support analyst to capture my keystrokes and steal my password?

Comment: They will have the same privileges as you.  So if you can view your own passwords, so can they.  (If you can view these in your browser settings, so can they.  If you can copy the file from your browser's profile folder, so can they...) If you have locked down privileges it should prevent them from installing a keylogger or something similar and accessing those things after the session is over.  (So if you can install software, they can install software too.)

Comment: Thanks @pcalkins!  It sounds like they would have had to install the software on my computer in order to capture my keystrokes? I can only install software if I enter admin credentials on a per-case basis.